# How to add from textbox to datagridview for same barcode without duplicates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox

How to add from textbox to datagridview for same barcode without duplicates in vb.net.

I tried the code I posted below but I tried the third time in the column "Qty" it remains valued at 2 should be worth 3 is there something wrong with my code.

Thanks

```
 Private Sub BtxtBarcode_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles BtxtBarcode.KeyPress
        Try
            If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
                If BtxtBarcode.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox("Please enter item barcode.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
                Else
                    GetItemData(BtxtBarcode.Text)
                    Dim iRow As Integer
                    If DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 = 0 Then
                        iRow = 1
                    Else
                        iRow = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 2).Cells(1).Value.ToString()) + 1
                    End If
                    Dim Qty As Integer = 1
                    Dim Found As Boolean = False
                    For j = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                        If Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value) = BtxtBarcode.Text.ToString() Then
                            Found = True
                            DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(4).Value = Qty + 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Not Found Then
                        itemtransfers.Add(New ItemTransfers With {
                        .No = iRow,
                       .CodeProduct = _CodeProduct,
                       .Barcode = _BBarcode,
                       .Qty = Qty
                        })
                        DataGridView1.Bind(itemtransfers)
                        BtxtBarcode.Clear()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: add textbox to datagridview-2]

Desired results

| No | CodeProduct | Barcode | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST 1000 | 01-22222222 | 3 |

Comment: What does `DataGridView1.Bind` do? I don't think that is a built-in method of `DataGridView`

Comment: @SSS , I'm using Kimtoo's DataGridView Provider Binding Library. So  it's the same as `datagridview1.DataSource` only the difference is that it does binding based on the list of T

Comment: In that case you should be using `DataGridView1.Rows(j).DataBoundItem` to manipulate data. I'm not familiar with that package, so you will need to work out the exact typecasting back to your `ItemTransfers` class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the object binding package you are using, but you can try something like

```
DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(j).DataBoundItem, ItemTransfers).Qty = Qty + 1
```

For data-bound grids, it is best to manipulate the data object directly, and let the datagridview update itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after updating your answer i.e. I change the code from `DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(4).Value = Qty + 1` to  `DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(j).DataBoundItem, ItemTransfers).Qty = Qty + 1` but there is an error on the second time I call the same barcode `Object Refence not set to an instance of an object`